# How to input dataset to the Swarm algorithms in SwarmPackage of Python and how to extract the optimized feature list to give input to the classifiers?

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning

The description of the [SwarmPackagePy](https://github.com/SISDevelop/SwarmPackagePy) library on Github writes:

Every algorithm has arguments listed below:
n: number of agents
function: test function
lb: lower limits for plot axes
ub: upper limits for plot axes
dimension: space dimension
iteration: number of iterations

Every algorithm has methods listed below:
get_agents(): returns a history of all agents of the algorithm
get_Gbest(): returns the best position of algorithm

Where do we give our dataset as input and how do we extract the optimized feature subset to give input to the classifiers?

Comment: Hello @desertnaut. I see you think I have made no attempts at this but I have spent about 3 weeks pondering over the problem and trying to see the code of the swarm functions trying to understand where the feature set is input, but I am still balnk on it. If you think I did not try searching for a solution then you must know easily available resources that describe what I am asking here. Kindly post the links to those easliy availbale and understandable resources so that I can go through them and ask more specific questions if needed.

Comment: You are missing the point; 'no attempt' here means *no shared attempt*, and the link (which is included for your benefit, as it provides really useful *advice*) makes it clear: "If we did try and **don’t** share our efforts with others, those attempting to help may *duplicate our efforts instead of providing a working solution*, wasting not only our time but theirs as well". We do want to help, and we do have a reputation of doing so, but this doesn't mean that you should not bother including even a link to the said Github repo...

Comment: Oh..okay.. I have added the link. I thought I have included the important info in the description but it is always better to point to the source. Please see if you can help now. :)

Comment: The missing link was just the most obvious omission... Until you share what exactly you have tried, and what exactly your issues are, nobody here will be able to offer any help (even what the library has to do with *machine learning*, *classifiers*, and *feature subsets* is by no means obvious, to me at least)...